# Was a satellite ever brought back to earth and then launched again?

Tags: artificial-satellite, reuse

Today I was reading a children's book (*Ich hab einen Freund, der ist Astronaut* ... my translation: "I have a friend who's an astronaut") to my son.

On one page it claims that (translation by me):

> Sometimes astronauts use the gripper arm [of the space shuttle] to capture defective satellites. On earth these [satellites] are repaired and then put back to space.

From all I know this is just wrong. But to be sure:

**Was a satellite ever brought back to earth, repaired and then put back into space?**

Note that Space Shuttles and other "transporters" don't count.

Comment: I'd appreciate help with tagging :)

Comment: Note, only Palapa B-2 and Westar 6 actually returned to space. But a bunch of satellites were repaired in orbit.

Comment: Wow. That was unexpected. Thanks a lot for pointing me to that other question (and most of all, its answer).